# putting like button on web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems with posting a like button to a web page. I copied the code from the like button page, but nothing shows up. I posted both the java script code and the code for the plugin, but nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong? I followed the directions exactly.

Comment: How can we help you? You even didn't pot your code...

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear and you don't tell us what's wrong.

In case you are talking about the Facebook button look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
As you can see on this page there is a warning that may be your problem:

> If you implemented the Like button before November 7, 2012, read this notice.

```
On November 7, 2012, we updated how the Like button functions with respect to content restrictions, publishing updates and integration with the built-in like action.

If you implemented Like buttons before this update, read Like Button Migration since your implementation may require changes to continue working.

After July 2013 migration, the Like button required an absolute URL in the href parameter.
```

Comment: To get this answer I just typed "Facebook like button" on my search engine and clicked on the first link. Facebook added a [breaking change](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#july2013) from July 10, 2013